# Ошибки с использованием Postegre SQL в Qt - C++ Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt

Всем привет,

пишу консольное приложение для Windows и Linux
скачал Qt 5.9, msvc2013_64, открыл Visual Studio, добавил директории для include/lib файлов, все слинковал и пишу такой код:
Программа должна подключаться к Postgre SQL серверу и обновлять БД.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QtSql\QSqlDatabase.h>

int main() {
    <...>
    QSqlDatabase db;
    printf("msg\n");
    <...>
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда исполнение доходит до создания экземпляра класса QSqlDatabase (или другой компоненты QSql*), программа завершается с кодом (1) и выдает сообщение об ошибке следующего характера:

`"Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50900) with this library (version 0x50600)"`
У меня также была установлена версия Qt 5.8, при попытке подложить моей программе Qt5sql.dll из папки 5.8, ошибка превращается уже в
`"Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50800) with this library (version 0x50600)"`

Я сделал вывод, что нужно или опуститься на версию Qt 5.6, чтобы не заморачиваться, или же перекомпилировать модуль SQL.
В конечном итоге при попытке подсунуть Q5Sql.dll из SDK 5.6, получаю ошибку

`"Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50602) with this library (version 0x50600)"`
На этом мои попытки менять версии так грубо закончились, не понимаю в чем дело.
Нужно перекомпилировать библиотеку Qt Sql для версии 5.9, только я не понимаю как это сделать.

При том нужно добавить, что код Qt, не трогающий SQL, не роняет приложение.
Т.е. проблема только в SQL модулях.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался?